# What considerations in mongo should I have turning indexed numeric attributes into strings

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

We are moving to a new system which is forcing us to use strings instead of Int32s for an id. Not to be confused with the _id. None of our queries are intending to change, but they are a lot slower. They effectively went from 170ms to 1.4minutes. We have a lot of lookups in this main query, if it wasn't proprietary I would post it here, but really it's not the query since only the database attributes that we use for lookups has changed from a number to a string. They are already indexed on that using unique and descending indexes, but maybe there is more consideration I might need for it? Effectively this change made the attribute "a12343cgr3h" from a number like 4321. I personally believe numbers are faster and I have doubts we can make this any faster, but I'm hoping we can speed it up somehow, I just believe the solution is out of my wheelhouse. I'm not sure if I need a text index or if there are other solutions I need to change. Most of the queries use a simple find({id: "a12343cgr3h"}), but then we have some aggregate queries with lots of lookups and nested arrays that also have their own lookups. I can't post the query otherwise I would. Any thoughts on what I should do in terms of indexes or anything else I need to consider when changing an indexed numeric attribute to a text attribute that could be slowing down the query?

Comment: can you provide a bit more information? what are the scale of the collections your joining? did scale also increase as part of this change? it would help if you could post puesdo code of those queries  and schemas ?as it's possible we could optimize those as well.

Is restructuring the schema a possibility?

Comment: There is about 10K-100K records in each depending on which one we are trying to join. Most of the code is in javascript with a lot of checking for things like if there is this filter present in the request then we add this lookup to the query. I don't think I have a good way to show it, but I can probably mask everything. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Found out it's the driver that is slow. When running through the mongo shell it takes about a second. When running with the mongo driver it is slow